# Need help in output for Oracle PLSQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

Am currently working on oracle PLSQL function to  list the project numbers, titles and the names of employees who work on each project.

For this function, I am required to obtain an output as such:
[Fragmented example]

```
1001 Computation: Alvin, Peter
1002 Study methods: Bob, Robert
1003 Racing car: Robert
```

Here is the output I am currently having.
SQL> execute PROJECTGROUPS;

```
1001 Computation: Alvin
1001 Computation: Ami
1001 Computation: Michael
1001 Computation: Peter
1001 Computation: Wendy
1002 Study methods: Bob
1002 Study methods: Robert
1003 Racing car: Bob
1003 Racing car: Robert
1004 Football: Douglass
1004 Football: Eadger
1005 Swimming: Douglass
1005 Swimming: Eadger
1006 Training: Aban
1006 Training: Carl
```

[Current Code]

```
SQL> set echo on
SQL> set feedback on
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> set pagesize 200
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> --
SQL> -- Task 01
SQL> --
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJECTGROUPS
  2  IS
  3  Previous_pnum PROJECT.P#%type := -1;
  4  --
  5  begin
  6  for currentRow IN(select p.P#, p.PTITLE, e.NAME
  7  from PROJECT p LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE e
  8  on p.d# = e.d#
  9  WHERE p.P# IN(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006)
 10  ORDER BY p.P#, p.PTITLE, e.NAME)
 11  --
 12  --
 13  loop
 14  if currentRow.P# is not null then
 15  dbms_output.put_line(currentRow.P# || ' ' || currentRow.PTITLE || ': ' || currentRow.NAME);
 16  end if;
 17  Previous_pnum := currentRow.P#;
 18  end loop;
 19  dbms_output.put_line(NULL);
 20  END;
 21  /

Procedure created.
```

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is listagg function.

Here is the SQL -

```
SELECT p.P#
      ,p.PTITLE
      ,listagg(e.NAME, ',') within group (order by e.name) employee_names
  FROM PROJECT p 
      ,EMPLOYEE e
 WHERE p.P# IN(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006)
   AND p.d# = e.d#(+)
 GROUP
    BY p.P#
      ,p.PTITLE
 ORDER 
    BY p.P#
      ,p.PTITLE
```

Comment: Is it possible to share how I can add this into my code. I have tried it so far but getting results: 9/2  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/60  PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: please use explicit join syntax rather than comma-seperated table joins which is too old.

Comment: It is a matter of personal taste. For me, the traditional way is much more compact and elegant, much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG()` function to return the string in order to print directly with alias (`str`), and print such as `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( str )` :

```
SELECT p.p#||' '||p.ptitle||': '||LISTAGG( e.name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY e.name ) AS str
  FROM project p
  LEFT JOIN employee e
    ON p.d# = e.d#
 WHERE p.p# BETWEEN 1001 AND 1006
 GROUP BY p.p#, p.ptitle
 ORDER BY p.p#, p.ptitle;
```

we don't know your sample data set. Perhaps you'd need `INNER JOIN` depending on the data. Btw, it seems need to fix the data structure of `project` table. The column `d#` should be moved to another(the third) table I think.